# Are end-of-life wishes perceived differently by children?

Tags: death

I understand more care and caution are needed in fulfilling end-of-life wishes of children under palliative care.

Are there any studies on how the fulfillment of such wishes affect children differently from adults who are terminally ill? Or is there no difference?